# KrakenJS not overriding with development.json

Tags: kraken.js

Configurations from config/development.json is not overriding the default config/config.json for me.

I am using KrakenJS's own passport-example as my base code.

I have set the NODE_ENV to 'development', and added an "env": "development" to development.json and "env": "production" to the default config.json.

Also added a console log from spec.js:

```
return {
    onconfig: function(config, next) {

        var dbConfig = config.get('databaseConfig'),
            cryptConfig = config.get('bcrypt');

        console.log('Config Environment is: config.env: ', config.get('env'));

        crypto.setCryptLevel(cryptConfig.difficulty);
        db.config(dbConfig);
        // userLib.addUsers();
        next(null, config);
    }
};
```

And here is the output from the console:

[development] Listening on http://localhost:8000
Config Environment is: config.env:  production
db connection open

I need a different callback URL for facebook login for development. But I am not able to see the development config overriding the config.json. What am I missing here? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Adding `"env": "anything"` isn't useful -- Kraken itself sets the configured env based on the environment variable.

How did you set the environment variable?

Comment: This "env" is just for debugging, so I know which config file is loaded. I read from here: https://github.com/krakenjs/kraken-js the configuration section, the overriding of development.json should be automatic.

Comment: I have set the NODE_ENV to "development"

Comment: Yeah. So remove the 'env' entry from your config files -- right now, the config file gets loaded and overwrites your environment variable.

Comment: No, it doesn't. I just renamed it to name: config1 and name: config2, it is still loading the production (config1), not the development config file. How should I configure the confit so it loads the development config file? Thanks

Comment: That should be sufficient: the development configuration is called `development.json` ?

Comment: Yes, development.json is the development configuration file.

Comment: One of. The main config file is read, too. One overlays the other, merging parts.

Comment: @shallowcal, Unable to reproduce this. I cloned the the passport example repo, and followed your steps.

Can you provide a link to your github fork of the project so we can replicate from your codebase?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want `env` in the config files -- that should be set by the `NODE_ENV` environment variable only. The order `confit` loads the config files will overwrite the previous value, leaving you with the wrong value.

Comment: Pls see my reply in the comments. I have properly set the NODE_ENV, the environment in the JSON is just a text for displaying which config was being loaded. I could name it tom and jerry or anything else, that was not the issue here. The config files are automatically loaded or overwritten based on the NODE_ENV variable. How should I configure the confit so it does?